# Why video using you tube player API is not playing on mobile device?

Tags: javascript, iphone, youtube-api

I have a website where user logon and has to watch a video. After that user has to answer 5 questions after the video has finished loading. I have been able to allow the user to play the video. The next part is adding a link to the page that appears as a button. It works fine when running on Google Chrome and Safari, but not on iOS simulator

Here are the possible problems.

1. Is there any way i can run, or view those html, css, & js files on my iPhone 6?
2. Is there something wrong with my code or is there anything i can add to allow the video to run on mobile device?
3. My video is not showing up either.

Following is my code.

```
// youtube video
var player;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        videoId: '0Bmhjf0rKe8',
        events: {
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

// add link
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data === 0) {
        addLink();
    }
}

// when video ends
function addLink() {
    var link = document.createElement("A");
    var text = document.createTextNode("Continue");
    link.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById("housing").appendChild(link);
    link.id = "link"
}
```

Here is a [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wrestlerkid2000/heqc5pbb/11/).

Comment: Is there a reason for you to use this approach ? There are hundreds of other ways to add video to your html page.

Comment: Apple devices including simulators have `Safari`as there default browser which is of `-webkit-` type like Google Chrome. Try running the website on actual device, it should work.